# PHP regex getting additional data

Tags: php, regex

I have many rows of data in the following format

```
<terminal:Text>1  #AY5767 F9 A9 P. J9 C9 D9 I9 Y9 LHRMIA 0945 1410   *  777 0E</terminal:Text>
<terminal:Text>        B9 H9 K9 M9 L9 V9 S9 N9 Q9 O9 G9 </terminal:Text>
```

The terminal:Text elements are loaded and looped over.  At the moment I am doing

```
$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.test.com/terminal', 'Text');
$elNum = 0;
while ( $elNum < $elements->length ) {

    $flightInfo = $elements->item($elNum)->nodeValue;

    if (preg_match('/^\\d/', $flightInfo) === 1) {

        if(preg_match('/(\d+[^#]*\#(\p{Lu}{2})\s*(\d{1,4})\b)(\s*\K[\w ]+(?=\s+\p{Lu}{6}))\s([A-Z]{3})([A-Z]{3})\s(.+)/', $flightInfo, $matches)===1){
            $fltcode = $matches[2].$matches[3];
            $ffrom = $matches[5];
            $fto = $matches[6];
            $other = $matches[7];

            $seatString = $matches[4];
            $seatInfo = explode( " ", trim( $seatString ) );

            $this->flights[$fltcode] = array(
                "flightNumber" => $fltcode,
                "from" => $ffrom,
                "to" => $fto,
                "seats" => $seatInfo,
                "other" => $other
            );
        }
    }
    ++$elNum;
}
```

That pretty much captures all the data I need from the first row.  However, the second row is related to the first row, and the data in the second row should be added to the $seatInfo.  I was thinking something similar to this

```
while ($elNum + 1 < $elements->length && preg_match('/^\s*[A-Z][0-9\.\-]/i', $elements->item($elNum + 1)->nodeValue)) {
    ++$elNum;
    $seatInfo = trim($seatInfo) . " " . $elements->item($elNum)->nodeValue;
}
```

It doesnt quite seem to work though.  What would be the best way to link the second row to the $seatInfo content?

Thanks

Expected output

```
$seatString = F9 A9 P. J9 C9 D9 I9 Y9 B9 H9 K9 M9 L9 V9 S9 N9 Q9 O9 G9
```

Comment: How are the two code blocks related? The first block is leaving `$seatInfo` as an array, but the second block is treating it as a string.

Comment: Your question and your goal are unclear, could you add the expected result with your example string to your question. (like a print_r of the result array)

Comment: The first block takes the string of seats and adds it to an array.  I need to add the second line of seats to the first line of seats and add them all to the array